# VB.NET How to display a messagebox if no radio button selected and clear them when next button clicked

Tags: vb.net

Hi I'm creating an examination system as school project. I'm using visual studio 2010 and back-end is MS Access 2007. I have 4 radio buttons and 1 button command(NEXT) on a form.

How to display a Messagebox if all 4 radio buttons were unselected? Also , if one of the 4 radio buttons was selected, the answer should be inserted to the database and when the next button clicked to proceed to the next question the radio buttons should be cleared.

My current code as shown below do as: If i checked the `radiobtnA` the answer A will be inserted to the database and when i click next button the radio buttons will all clear.

[image]

Below is my code:

`Private Sub nxtBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nxtBTN.Click
    Dim EQcorrAnswer As Integer = 0
    Dim strAnswer As String = ""

    If radiobtnA.Checked = True Then strAnswer = "A"
    radiobtnA.Checked = False
    If radiobtnB.Checked = True Then strAnswer = "B"
    radiobtnB.Checked = False
    If radiobtnC.Checked = True Then strAnswer = "C"
    radiobtnC.Checked = False
    If radiobtnD.Checked = True Then strAnswer = "D"
    radiobtnD.Checked = False

     If corrAnsTB.Text = strAnswer Then
        EQcorrAnswer = 1
        intcorrAnswer += 1
    End If

    ExecNonQuery("UPDATE Examinee SET score = " & intcorrAnswer & " AND timefin ='" & timetxt.Text & "' AND datetaken ='" & TXTDate.Text & "' Where tempID = '" & tempIDTB.Text & "'")


    Try
        ExecNonQuery("INSERT INTO ExamResult (tempID,QuestionID,answer,correct) VALUES('" & tempIDTB.Text & "','" & questIDTB.Text & "','" & strAnswer & "'," & EQcorrAnswer & ")")

        If inc <> maxrows - 1 Then
            inc = inc + 1
            navigaterecords()`

Comment: I can't really tell, I can only assume however I would think you're open to SQL injection. It won't fix the issue but you should consider SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings together.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few things that would make it much easier for you, instead of using that insightly `If [...]` Statement!

My suggestion is to first add an event handler that handles the 'CheckChanged' Event for all your RadioButtons:

```
Dim SelectedAnswer As RadioButton = Nothing
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonA.CheckedChanged, RadioButtonB.CheckedChanged, RadioButtonD.CheckedChanged, RadioButtonC.CheckedChanged

End Sub
```

---

And also add the following to the above Sub.
This will filter the events so it only focuses on the event that involves one of the RadioButtons being Checked, and not UnChecked.

```
    If DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
        SelectedAnswer = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
        strAnswer = SelectedAnswer.Name.Substring(8, 1)
        'And potentially anything else you wanted to add could go here
    Else
        SelectedAnswer = Nothing
        'Or here
    End If
```

What this (above) is doing (to be very thorough) is using the 'sender' which will be the object that triggered the event. And since we have 4 objects that it could be, we use DirectCast() to convert the generic Object Type it gives us back to what it actually is (a Radio Button).

TryCast() could also be used, and can be useful for checking to see if it Casted (or converted) the Type successfully by simply checking to make sure it's not `Nothing`. It uses the same parameters as what i am going to explain below for DirectCast().

So for the first parameter we input the Object 'sender' and for the second we use the Type of the Object we want use to convert the 'sender' to. So we use RadioButton.

Since we aren't expecting any other type to trigger this event we can use DirectCast() without any problems.

---

Now for your Button Click Event you provided:

```
Dim strAnswer As String = ""
Private Sub nxtBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nxtBTN.Click
    If SelectedAnswer = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing selected, silly :p")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim EQcorrAnswer As Integer = 0
    SelectedAnswer.Checked = False
    SelectedAnswer = Nothing

    If corrAnsTB.Text = strAnswer Then
        EQcorrAnswer = 1
        intcorrAnswer += 1
    End If
    ...
    ...
End Sub
```

I used an `If [...]` to check if there was an answer actually selected.
If not, display message and Exit the Sub to stop it from going any further.

Then If the Sub didn't Exit, change the selected RadioButton (`SelectedAnswer`) to unchecked, and reset the variable if we haven't a need for it anymore.

---

Then the remaining code (which i hadn't included in the last snipet) would go in place of the `...`'s.

---

Hope I was able to help you, and explain everything well enough!
And of course this is a suggestion, so you could do it anyway you'd like.